# Does Rank $[A|b]$ is same as Rank $[R|b]$ for all $b \in \mathbb{R^{4}}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

Let $R$ be RREF of a $4  \times 4$ real matrix $A$ and let the $3^{rd}$ column of $R$ is $\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
1\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$. Then

> **Does Rank $[A|b]=[R|b]$ for all $b \in \mathbb{R^{4}}$?**

**Solution i tried**- If we consider the $A=\begin{bmatrix}
 1&0  &  0& 0\\ 
 0& 1 & 1 &0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  0& 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$  then we can see its RREF will be see as that of $A$, then the given statement should be true,

But in answer it is mentioned that it is false , how can I show that this is false

Thank you

Comment: One example where the statement is true is not a proof. In particular one where $A$ and $R$ are the same …

Comment: Replace the lowest two rows by $1$'s and also set $A_{24}=1$ and consider $b$ the vector consisting of $1$'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{bmatrix}\quad\text{with}\quad
\operatorname{rref}(A) = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{bmatrix} =: R.
$$
For $b = (1,0,0,0)^{\mathrm t}$ we have
$$
\operatorname{rank}[A|b]=3\neq 2=\operatorname{rank}[R|b].
$$